# PHP pulling data from database and converting date into iso8610 JavaScript date

Tags: php, javascript, sql, iso8601

I have php code that pulls information needed from the database. The php date code is formatted in "format("Y-m-d H:i:s")". I am trying to get these dates from the database and add them to a calendar using JavaScript. I loop there the events that I want to add to the calendar. I have to different ways I found solutions for but neither one works.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    <?php for($x = 0; $x < count($events); $x++) { ?>
          var dateToConvert = new Date('<?php echo date(DATE_ISO8601, strtotime($events[$x]["startDate"])); ?>');
          var startDate = dateToConvert.toISOString();
          var endDate = '<?php echo date(DATE_ISO8601, strtotime($events[$x]["endDate"])); ?>';
          var events = [
             {
               title: '<?php echo $events[$x]["name"]; ?>',
               start: new Date(startDate),
               end: endDate
             }
          ];
    <?php } ?>
</script>
```

I am assuming that I am missing something minor but I can't figure it out. I used the Chrome debugger and this is what I have as input. (2013-03-18T01:00:00-0600) It doesn't seem to have the Z at the end like it should.

The value in the database is (2013-03-18 01:00:00).

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You should not pass dates in any string format. Instead, pass them as numbers.

```
var dateToConvert = new Date();
dateToConvert.setTime(<?php echo strtotime($events[$x]['startDate']); ?>000);
```

This will work a lot more reliably. Note that the three zeroes are there because JS handles time in milliseconds whereas PHP does so in seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Your ISO time is formatted correctly. The 'Z' on the end of a date-time indicates 'Zulu time', which is the UCT timezone.

Therefore, you would only specify 'Z' if you haven't specified a different timezone.

In your case, the date you've quoted does include a time zone (`-6000`), so I would not expect to see a 'Z'.

See the Wikipedia page for more info: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_zone_designators

For moving date/time values between PHP and Javascript, I would say the easiest way to do it is simply to use a unix timestamp. It's a simple integer value, so there's no formatting to think about, and both languages understand it perfectly. The only caveat is that in Javascript it's in microseconds vs seconds for PHP, so you need to multiply or divide by 1000. But that's simple enough.